# Changing the path of getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH) in runtime

Tags: java

Is it possible to change the PATH of the Java code `getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH)` in runtime? I would like to have an edit box so that the user can specify i.e http://site.com/image.png for the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` if the resource is not on the classpath (i.e., not deployed on your server). It is not what it is intended for.

To load resources from a HTTP URL, use `HttpURLConnection`